# How to create array items by specify a key that includes hierachy?

Tags: php, arrays

Given original codes as:

```
foreach($option as $name=>$value)
    $array[$name] = $value;
```

and $name as

```
button[0][text], button[0][value], button[1][text], spider[0][name], ...
```

The result array would be

```
array('button[0][text]' => 'its text',
    'button[0][value]' => 'its value',
    'button[1][text]' => 'its text',
    'spider[0][name]' => 'its name',
)
```

However, what i want is

```
array('button' => array( array('text'=>'its text', 'value'=>'its value'), // this is $array[button][0]
                         array('text'=>'its text') // this is $array[button][1]
                  ),
      'spider' => array( array('name'=>'its name') // this is $array[spider][0]
                  )
)
```

How could i do this?
    ...

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Please elaborate on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look that bad, but you should avoid eval. Easily achieved by matching all keys with preg_match.

```
if(preg_match('/^\w+?[(\d+?)][(\w+?)]$/', $name, $matches)) {
    $myarray[$matches[1]][$matches[2]][$matches[3]] = $value;
```

Not tested, but I'm sure you'll get the idea.

Comment: agree, that's why i want to see more solutions and you gave a good example. the only problem is the key number is not known. it can be 2, 3 or more

Answer (score 0):

I just worked out a solution myself, but still want to see other solutions. For your interesting, paste my solution here:

```
if(preg_match('/^([^\[\]]+)(\[.+\])$/', $name, $matches)) {
    eval('$myarray[$matches[1]]'. $matches[2]. ' = $value;');
```